# Icons are not displaying in Android application

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu, android-icons

I am complete newbie when it comes to Android applications. Please bear with me. I am trying to make an menu options bar but somehow the icons are not displaying.

I had looked for answers to this question on stackoverflow and the answer that I came across was "On Android 3.0+, the preferred approach for the options menu (a spillover menu in the action bar) will not show icons. If you have android targetSdkVersion of 11 or higher, icons will never show up in menus on Android 3.0+. The icons will show up if you promote an options menu item to be a toolbar button, and the icons will show up on Android 1.x/2.x devices." I am sorry but I am not sure what that means. Can someone please direct me in the right direction? Any help will be appreciated!

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly. Here is my code so far.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.useoptionsmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
    return true;
    case R.id.help:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
    return true;
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    android:title="About"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:showAsAction="always"
     android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
    android:title="Help"/>

</menu>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.useoptionsmenu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.useoptionsmenu.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.useoptionsmenu.About"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.useoptionsmenu.Help"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_help" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this to the item you want to display in the header:

```
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

so that your menu will be:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    android:title="About"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
     android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
    android:title="Help"/>

</menu>
```

remove the line android:showAsAction="ifRoom" from the item you won't display in your header.

Comment: If I make the changes mentioned above, my app crashes. :(

Comment: try to set only one ifRoom

Comment: can you attach the logcat?

Comment: 11-24 18:39:29.615: E/AndroidRuntime(936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 18:39:29.615: E/AndroidRuntime(936): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS, SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM, and SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER are mutually exclusive.
11-24 18:39:29.615: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setShowAsAction(MenuItemImpl.java:555)
11-24 18:39:29.615: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:409)

Comment: Hi iGio90, it is still not working. It think it has something to do with "promote an options menu item to be a toolbar button" as mentioned by a user in a previous post. But I do not know what that means and how I should change my app to do so. :(

Comment: no, it doesn't metter.. please, attach the new logcat.. it have to be different now!

Comment: 11-25 00:47:04.182: D/AndroidRuntime(914): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-25 00:47:04.182: D/AndroidRuntime(914): CheckJNI is ON
11-25 00:47:04.252: D/dalvikvm(914): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-25 00:47:04.263: D/dalvikvm(914): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-25 00:47:04.352: D/dalvikvm(914): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-25 00:47:04.352: D/dalvikvm(914): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-25 00:47:04.482: E/cutils-trace(914): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: 11-25 00:47:04.352: D/dalvikvm(914): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-25 00:47:04.482: E/cutils-trace(914): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-25 00:47:05.201: D/AndroidRuntime(914): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-25 00:47:05.262: D/AndroidRuntime(914): Shutting down VM
11-25 00:47:05.272: D/dalvikvm(914): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-25 00:47:06.103: D/AndroidRuntime(925): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<11-25 00:47:06.103: D/AndroidRuntime(925): CheckJNI is ON

Comment: 11-25 00:47:06.182: D/dalvikvm(925): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-25 00:47:06.242: D/dalvikvm(925): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-25 00:47:06.332: D/dalvikvm(925): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-25 00:47:06.332: D/dalvikvm(925): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-25 00:47:06.531: E/cutils-trace(925): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-25 00:47:07.332: D/AndroidRuntime(925): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am

Comment: 11-25 00:47:07.342: D/dalvikvm(925): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 163 unimplemented (abstract) methods
11-25 00:47:07.422: I/ActivityManager(288): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.useoptionsmenu/.MainActivity} from pid 925
11-25 00:47:07.442: W/WindowManager(288): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (328x546) to layer 21010 11-25 00:47:07.582: D/AndroidRuntime(925): Shutting down VM
11-25 00:47:07.582: D/jdwp(925): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select

Comment: 11-25 00:47:07.582: D/dalvikvm(925): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-25 00:47:09.502: I/ARMAssembler(36): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00008001_00000000 [ 89 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x41f8d620:0x41f8d7d8] in 1434541 ns                                        This is the entire logcat message. I do not get any errors while compiling....But the icons do not display :(

Comment: The comment section has a character limit and so I had to post my entire logcat like this.